# Form values not updating - React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I want to update a form field's values despite having successfully submitted the form, saved the data to state and persisted it to local storage.

Currently, when I try to change the value of a form field when it's populated with `defaultValues` (set from local storage), the new updated value that I intend to save is immediately replaced with the old value, almost like no new value was submitted.

My code:

**State:**

```
  const [submittedData, setSubmittedData] =
    useState<PersonalInformationFormInput | null>(null);
  const [defaultValues, setDefaultValues] =
    useState<PersonalInformationFormInput>({
      firstName: "",
//...
    });
```

**RHF useForm hook:**

```
  const {
    register,
    formState: { errors },
    watch,
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
    formState,
    trigger,
    setError,
  } = useForm<PersonalInformationFormInput>({
    resolver: zodResolver(FormSchema),
    defaultValues,
  });
```

**Retrieve form values from local storage and set state:**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof localStorage !== "undefined") {
      const storedData = localStorage.getItem("personalInformationData");
      if (storedData) {
        const parsedData = JSON.parse(storedData);
        setSubmittedData(parsedData);
        setDefaultValues(parsedData);

        // Set the form values using setValue
        Object.keys(parsedData).forEach((fieldName) => {
          const field: keyof PersonalInformationFormInput =
            fieldName as keyof PersonalInformationFormInput;
          setValue(field, parsedData[fieldName]);
        });

      }
    }
  }, []);
```

**onSubmit:**

```
  const onSubmit = (data: PersonalInformationFormInput) => {

    if (!formState.isValid) {
      console.log("Validation errors:", formState.errors);
      return;
    }

    // store submitted data in local state
    setSubmittedData(data);

    // store submitted data in localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("personalInformationData", JSON.stringify(data));

    // Reset the form with the new data
    //setDefaultValues(data); // tried this (not working)
  };
```

**snippet of form:**

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <div>
            <h2>
              First name
              <span>*</span>
            </h2>
            <input
              type="text"
              {...register("firstName")}
            />
            {errors?.firstName?.message && (
              <p>
                {errors.firstName.message}
              </p>
            )}
          </div>
          <div>
            <button
              type="submit"
              // onClick={handleNextStep}
            >
              Next Step
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RHF's [watch](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/watch) method to watch specified inputs and return their values. Here's how it would work in this case:

Callback version of `watch`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = watch((value, { name, type }) =>
      console.log(value, name, type)
    );
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, [watch]);
```

This will automatically register values. It's up to you to unsubscribe when done.

Or target a specific field:

```
const watchedFirstName = watch('firstName')
```

then set the value in `onSubmit`:

```
setValue('firstName`, watchedFirstName)
```

If valid, the updated values will be persisted to local storage:

```
    localStorage.setItem("personalInformationData", JSON.stringify(data));
```

and displayed in the form fields/on page refresh.
So the user can update a form field in case they submitted inaccurate information.

I would recommend the latter approach of watching for changes in each individual input rather than all the values with the callback as I noticed issues with performance.